# What's the word or phrase used specifically to describe someone who is only concerned with physical appearence of others?

Tags: compounds

I believe it starts with み and is something like 'only has an eye for beauty', but it's been a long time since I used it. I believe it's a kanji compound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the word [menkui](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%82%81%E3%82%93%E3%81%8F%E3%81%84&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss) (面食い).

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure about み, it could be 見た目重視, or maybe some other phrase starting with 見た目.